# math formulas in xml strings

Tags: android, xml, string, textview

I have wondered how to write math formulas in XML file like strings and then show them in TextView. E.g. like those formulas where negligible geometric progression formula.

And in addition;

I have  a problem crating text in single line.

Here is my TextView in LinearLayout.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/some" >
   </TextView>
```

and on virtual android device i get only like 50 chars... I have tried to use:

```
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
```

Here is what I want: get text smaller if it needs to be and fit to screen in single line without any chars missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get text smaller using `android:textSize="##sp"`, where ## is the size of the text you want. As for your first question, no idea... AFAIK I don't think you can perform math operations in xml. You will need to perform it in your java code and then use `.setText(Integer.toString(yourIntResultHere));`